# Weblog from Live Writer with Live ID authentication

Tags: authentication, windows-live-id, windows-live-writer

I'm currently developing a weblog engine. I use Live Id for authentication when logging in online. I'm building support for Live Writer thru the MetaWeblogAPI.

Is it possible to check Live ID authentication from within Live Writer? Does anyone know if this it is possible to do this myself? or do I have to create an alternative authentication mechanism for live writer and forget about Live ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a reaction from Microsoft:

"Unfortunately at the moment you will need to have an alternate authentication system to run parrallel with LiveID as LiveID can only be used for Live Spaces from within the Live Writer blog setup."

I guess that answers the question.